# How to implement a horizontal scrollview like an appstore

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to implement a scrollview like an appstore?
I'm going to scroll to the next content, when the scroll is done halfway

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement it simple with `FlatList`, using `horizontal` and `pagingEnabled` boolean props and `deviceWidth`;

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions, ScrollView, View, Text } from 'react-native';

const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },

  page: {
    width: deviceWidth
  },

});

const Slider = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView
      horizontal
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      pagingEnabled>
      <View style={styles.page}>
        <Text> This is View 1 </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.page}>
        <Text> This is View 2 </Text>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: Thanks, Like the image How can I display some of the next scroll content in the current scroll?

Comment: I was playing with it: just set the style of the *very first page only* to `width: deviceWidth * 0.9,` and all the others to `width: deviceWidth` and you get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The feature or functionality you are looking for is a simple horizontal slider.
Use could use this npm library to get what you are looking for: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-snap-carousel

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Flatlist](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist) which is React-Native's own component.

If you want to swipe the data Horizontally the use the prop `horizontal={true}` in the Flatlist.

Comment: Im not sure if this is the correct way to do it. The op asked for a "snapping" behaviour i'm not sure if flat list supports that already

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is what you want?

[image]

Source code: https://snack.expo.io/@gusgard/react-native-swiper-flatlist-2

Library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swiper-flatlist