# flatlist style with horizontal props

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When i set horizontal = {true} to FlatList, flex: 1 does not work on renderItem, what is the solution to this problem?

```
<FlatList
horizontal={true}
data={this.state.users}
renderItem={({item}) =>
<View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'blue'}}><Text>hello</Text></View>
                 }
keyExtractor={item => item.email}
/>
```

Comment: What end result would you like the for the items rendered in Flatlist?

Comment: @PritishVaidya I'm going to use the entire screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For covering the entire screen you can add the following styles

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native'
const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window)

...
<View style={{flex:1, width, backgroundColor:'blue'}}><Text>hello</Text></View>
```

Comment: Thanks, can you help with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52290749

Comment: Not sure about the snap behaviour on that one, but maybe this would help [`react-native-snap-carousel `](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel)

Answer (score 0):

Looks for me like you forgot to add the return statement in the renderItem function.

```html
renderItem={({item}) => return(
<View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'blue'}}><Text>hello</Text></View>)
```